# Starting Intermediate Level C# Class, with heavy focus on UML... Your best tips or experinced advice?

Tags: c#

I'm starting my 2nd class in C# programming through Kaplan online school. I have some limited interaction with the professor and the class online, but nothing like in an actual school. I'm about to go through "Modern Software Development Using C#.NET" by Richard Wiener. It seems the book as a extremely heavy focus on UML (which I don't even really know what that is right now!)

You experinced Csharpers.... any tips to keep in mind as I go through this to keep  in perspective how the modern software engineer works outside the classroom?

Any perspectives to share as I start understanding UML and intermediate C# programming?

Comment: I don't have much experience in C# but alot in online classes. Online classes are fiends. You might as well not waste money on that crap and just read books and teach yourself the subject matter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some companies will use UML everywhere. Some use it nowhere. I'm not a big fan myself - I prefer ad-hoc diagrams and plenty of other communication (notes on the diagram, actual *talking* etc).

The good thing about an ad-hoc approach is that you can leave it as vague as you like or make it really detailed. The bad thing about it is you can't generate any code from it - but I've never really liked generating code from UML. (Others swear by it, mind.)

You certainly don't *need* to know UML to learn C#.

Comment: seems upon first glances a "glorified flowcharting"... close?

Comment: No, not really. That sounds more like a sequence diagram. UML doesn't directly show progress in time - it shows relationships between types, and capabilities.

Comment: sounds like the class will be a challenge then; thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

UML would come very close to the end of the list of things that gave me insight into the complex world of programming. I find it very distracting when trying to design something, and too time consuming for real system descriptions. I have always thought it is important and tried to start my project with UML diagram, but it wasn't ever worth it.

Comment: wow. I won't try to get bogged down in it too much, and meet course requirements while working more on class building and understanding the framework better. Sounds like a better use of my time then.

Answer (score 2):

The bigger the projects you are working in the more you need a language to speak with, known by all members of the project team - a common language like UML! But you need not to start learning C# with UML.